# What is the relation between ∪A and A?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What I mean by this is ∪A⊆A, is A⊆∪A, or is ∪A=A? 
I'll give an example:
Let A be a set and A={B, C}, where B and C are sets. 
Now let's say B={1,2} and C={2,3}. This means A={{1,2},{2,3}} and ∪A={1,2,3}. 
Is A⊆∪A?

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is the set of all standard decks of cards (considered as sets; also pretend that every card is in a deck), then $\bigcup A$ is the set of all cards.

To restate your question: is every card a standard deck of cards?  Is every standard deck of cards a card?  Are cards and standard decks of cards the same thing?  These should tell you all you need to know about your general question.

For your example of $A=\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\}\}$, $\bigcup A = \{1,2,3\}$, ask yourself a similar question: are either of the *two* elements of $A$ equal to either of the *three* elements of $\bigcup A$?  Hint: some of them are numbers, and some of them are not.

Comment: Thank you for helping. My answer to your question would be no. I do have a question, however. You said A has two elements. So {1,2} is an element of A. Is 1 also an element of A? But {1} is not?

Comment: @settheorynoob here $A$ has elements which are sets. The set containing only $1$ not being an element of $A$